# I'm getting errors from the command sudo apt update and need help in fixing my computer

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, error-handling

i've been having errors updating stuff for a few months now on software updater and with the terminal using either sudo apt update or sudo apt-get update. ive tried quite a few tricks that have been used but nothing has changed so far.

this is my error message:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                      
Hit:6 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                                      
Get:3 http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                          
Get:5 http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Get:7 http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:3 http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:5 http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:7 http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I do not know if this is just normal or not but it's annoying me

Comment: There is something wrong with that mirror. Switch back to the default one

Comment: A quick look and to me the URL you're using isn't complete.. thus why you're getting your error.... but I didn't explore beyond highlighting details on your question & right click *open in new window* on my browser...   What I saw also gave me reasons why I'd not use it myself (*it didn't appear to be regularly maintained thus I'd explore further before I used it for security reasons*)